# iTunes misinterpreting subtitle character encoding

Tags: vim, itunes, encoding

I am attempting to use Turkish subtitles for a movie I recently bought on iTunes, except iTunes is interpreting the subtitles as if they were
encoded with ISO-8859-1. I believe the correct encoding [should be ISO/IEC 8859-9 which is explained here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-9).

So far I have been able to open the subtitles in Vim and change the encoding to ISO 8859-9 in order to confirm that the text was not just garbled and that this is actually an encoding issue. But the problem persists outside of saving the result, even re-opening the same file with Vim results in ISO 8859-1 characters yet again.

In Vim I used the following command:

```
:e ++enc=latin5
```

And for example in that case the word `daðýnýn` which is hard to understand becomes the more-intelligible `dağının`.

Except when I save this file in Vim and re-open it, it is again on ISO-8859-1 encoding.

I hope I have given sufficient detail here, this is not a topic I know much about. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with this for a couple of nights, of course the solution comes to me after posting a question.

I did the same thing as before. I opened the file in Vim, and reinterpreted the encoding as `latin5` using:

```
:e ++enc=latin5
```

I then opened a new file with:

```
:split newfile.srt
```

…and copied the now correctly interpreted text into the new file, which
after saving and checking on the command line:

```
file newfile.srt
newfile.srt: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

It used UTF-8, which correctly handles the Turkish characters. After loading the file into the itunes movie it shows up perfectly.

I’ll accept any answer that is simpler than this.

Comment: What is the name of the file you edit and what is its file path?